# how to select default value of ui select?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

could you please tell me how to set default value in UI -select .
here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/tCrEM4oC9iMSYZffbEAX?p=preview
I want **"Adrian"** should select as by default .could you please tell me how to set default value of **Adrian** age in model example (21) ?

```
<ui-select tagging tagging-label="new tag" multiple ng-model="model.multipleDemo" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color.age as color in people | filter:$select.search">
      {{color.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
<p>Selected: {{model.multipleDemo}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/0AAniDzf7fdKywh4Rfk5?p=preview

You can't use age in this case, otherwise it would find all persons that have the same age, and end up using the last one. You need either an unique id, or use the name, as I did on my plunker

`$scope.model.multipleDemo.push('Adrian');`

And on the select I've changed the repeat to `repeat="color.name as color in people | filter:$select.search"`.

Here's what would happen if you use the age instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/i6usxawmcnxYuqmH58kw?p=preview